# AVR microcontroller - jumping to specific address using the programcounter

Tags: avr, avr-gcc

I want my program to jump to a few-specific tasks every time an interrupt occures.

I was thinking of doing that by asserting addresses to the program counter to jump between tasks

First: how can i find where the task is located in memory?

Second: how can i assert an address to the program counter in C?

Comment: Sounds like XY-Problem https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem. You should explain what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

1. By passing the right arguments to GCC during the link step, you can configure GCC to generate a "map file" and it will tell you the addresses of all functions.  The addresses can change whenever you change anything in the code though.
2. You don't need to worry about function addresses or the program counter most of the time if you're programming in C.   Just define a function and call it.  Any introductory resource on C will have plenty of examples of this.

Comment: Using functions like that can cause race conditions : if another interrupt occure before finishing handling the previous one , i want to create custom "rules" for when to return to a function or not